# C++ AVX2: Seg fault when accessing address within array of arrays

Tags: c++, avx2

I am using AVX2 instructions to take a bitwise and operation between an array in an array, a 2D array called `test`, and a separate array called `joined_pos`. This is my code:

```
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <nmmintrin.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <immintrin.h>


#define ROUND_DOWN(x, s) ((x) & ~((s)-1))


int main()
{

    // Create two aligned arrays on a 32 byte boundary
    uint64_t test[10][50] __attribute__ ((aligned (32))) = {0};
    uint64_t join_pos[50]  __attribute__ ((aligned (32))) = {0};

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

        // get a pointer to the i-th aligned array in test
        uint64_t (*ptr1)[50] = test;
        ptr1 += i;

        // get a pointer to the first element in join_pos
        uint64_t *ptr2 = join_pos;

        // Cast ptr1 and ptr2 
            __m256i* ptr3 = (__m256i*) ptr1;
            __m256i* ptr4 = (__m256i*) ptr2;

        int counts = 0;
        int k = 0;

        for(; k < ROUND_DOWN(25,4); k+=4,ptr3++,ptr4++){
            __m256i val1 = _mm256_load_si256(ptr3); // This causes a segfault
            __m256i val2 = _mm256_load_si256(ptr4);
            __m256i val = _mm256_and_si256(val1, val2);
        }

    }

}
```

For some reason, when I try to load data from the 2D array `test`, I get a segfault. If I load the data using the function that loads unaligned memory (`_mm256_load_si256`), the code runs, but I did align `test`, so loading from from it should work.

Note: the code is compiled using `g++ -mavx2 -std=c++11 -g file.cpp -o file`.
`

Comment: you don't need to include 

`#include <emmintrin.h>`
`#include <nmmintrin.h>`
`#include <immintrin.h>` sepatatley just `#include <immintrin.h>` is enogh for `avx2`, BTW use `unaligned` instruction. there is no penalty. Unalighene violation is dead in modern CPUs.

Answer (score 2):

`test` may be aligned on a 32 byte boundary, but `test[1]` (`test + 1`) is not (since 50 8-byte elements occupy 400 bytes).  This is what is causing your segfault.

Comment: thanks. Do you know any other fixes besides creating another aligned array and copying `(test + i)` into it in each iteration?

Comment: but the elements of a 2D array are stored contiguously in memory, and the entire array is aligned

Comment: what if `test` was an aligned array of length 500, and suppose `__m256i* ptr3 = (__m256i*) (ptr1 + 50*it)`, will `ptr3` be aligned on a 32 byte boundary?

Comment: Fix: use `_mm256_loadu_si256`.  The array is aligned, which (with 8 byte `uint64_t` elements) will have elements 0, 4, 8, 12, etc. also aligned on 32 byte boundaries.  Elements 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, etc. are not on a 32 byte boundary.  Element `test[0][48]` is aligned, `test[0][49]` is not, `test[1][0]` is not, `test[1][1]` is not, `test[1][2]` is aligned.  `ptr3` will not be on a 32 byte boundary if `it` is odd.